# How to update a custom field value in JIRA using Python?

Tags: python, jira

I need to update a custom field in JIRA using Python. I checked other answers and they only provide solution for text fields. But I have a multi value list that I would like to update using Python.

I tried this but it doesn't work.

```
issue.update(fields={'customfield_13090': {'value':'64'}})
```

I'm getting this error when I run that line

```
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400 url: https://test.jira.com/rest/api/2/issue/1400908679
        text: Can not deserialize instance of java.lang.Long out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: N/A; line: -1, column: -1]
```

I inspected the list field and found that value 64 is the option value that I need to update if I want the list to have Implementation Services as the selected option.

```
<option selected="selected" value="64">
            Implementation Services
        </option>
```

Can some one please tell me what is the mistake in my line of code.

Comment: HTTP 400 means there's an issue with the way the param is being passed or it's contents (formatting related).

Comment: @FishingCode I also tried 64 with quotes, Edited that part and the error message. Could you please let me know what the issue is now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are close, but it should just be this:

```
 issue.update(fields={'customfield_13090': '64'})
```

if this doesn't work, I believe an alternate specify solution would be:

```
 issue.update(fields={'customfield_13090': [{'value':'64'}]})
```

This is just based on my research on configuring/updating JIRA searches.

Comment: The first line of code works but I have multiple customfields to update in single line. Can you help me with the code for that? I tried the following but it didn't work:


```
issue.update(fields={'customfield_13090': '64','customfield_12090': '35'})
```


ERROR:
```
jira.exceptions.JIRAError: JiraError HTTP 400 url: https://test.com/rest/api/2/issue/140090
        text: Could not find valid 'id' or 'value' in the Parent Option object.
```

Comment: As far as I know you will have to create separate `customfields` update. Also if you're going to have different types of custom fields there wouldn't be one quick way of doing it rather you have to specify each type line by line. I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
for a given 'customfield_13090': {
        'self': 'some link ',
        'value': '84',
        'id': '21104'
    }
```

Below code should work

```
issue.update(fields={'customfield_13090': {'value':'64'}})
```